# Assign to string instead of resultset for jdbc query

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I need to get the output of a jdbc query, but wherever I google, it returns a resultset. But, its just a single row. Here is my query

```
ResultSet rsLocationId = null;

rsLocationId = stmtLocation.executeQuery("SELECT apmcid FROM userbusinesstoapmc WHERE userbusinessid='"+userBusinessKey+"'");
```

It should return a single record as a string. How can I convert it? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and [bind](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString-int-java.lang.String-) the parameter, currently you are vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
String result = null;
final String sql = "SELECT apmcid FROM userbusinesstoapmc "
    + "WHERE userbusinessid=?";
try {
  ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  ps.setString(1, userBusinessKey);
  rs = ps.executeQuery();
  if (rs.next()) {
    result = rs.getString("apmcid");
  }
} catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  if (rs != null) {
    try {
      rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  if (ps != null) {
    try {
      ps.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```
ResultSet rsLocationId = null;String result="";

rsLocationId = stmtLocation.executeQuery("SELECT apmcid FROM userbusinesstoapmc WHERE userbusinessid='"+userBusinessKey+"'");
if(rsLocationId.next())
{
result=rsLocationId.getString('apmcid');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though your particular query only returns a single column, presumably some CHAR type if you expect the result to be a String, the executeQuery method returns a result set object, not a String object.  So, you have to process the result set to get your String data.  SpringLearner has provided a good example of how to do this.